# SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE as annotation in jackson json

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

**Is there a way to have the configuration of `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` as an annotation on the root element instead using `ObjectMapper`?**

For example I have:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "user")
public class UserWithRoot {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

Using ObjectMapper:

```
@Test
public void whenSerializingUsingJsonRootName_thenCorrect()
  throws JsonProcessingException {
    UserWithRoot user = new User(1, "John");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);

    assertThat(result, containsString("John"));
    assertThat(result, containsString("user"));
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "user":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"John"
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to have this `SerializationFeature` as an annotation and not as an configuration on the `objectMapper`?**

Using dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31158706/829571 See also: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues/33

Comment: @assylias yes saw that answer, too. But dont know how to get it as lower camel case. Need `user` and not `User`. Not sure if this is possible

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        UserWithRoot user = new UserWithRoot(1, "John");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String userJson = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(user);

        System.out.println(userJson);
    }

    @JsonTypeName(value = "user")
    @JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
    private static class UserWithRoot {
        public int id;
        public String name;
    }
}
```

`@JsonTypeName` and `@JsonTypeInfo` together make it possible.

Result:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "John"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I can't believe how complicated it is to just wrap a response.

Comment: @Sean - So true, it is complex and takes time getting used to. They could have come up with something like `@JsonWrapper` or `@JsonRootValue` which will take the name of the wrapper.

Comment: Is there a way we can support both format - with or without root?

Comment: spent a lot of time for this solution. @JsonRootName seemed promising but didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for this! Also it's work for deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been requested as:

```
 https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1022
```

so if anyone wants a challenge & a chance to make many users happy (it is something that'd be nice to have for sure), it's up for grabs :)

Aside from that one small thing worth noting is that you can use `ObjectWriter` to enable/disable `SerializationFeature`s.

```
String json = objectMapper.writer()
   .with(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
   .writeValueAsString(value);
```

in case you need to sometimes use this, other times not (`ObjectMapper` settings should not be changed after initial construction and configuration).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the it in the below way, so this property will be applied to throughout the objectMapper usage.

```
static {
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
}
```