# Remove leading array and / or root element label in produced json

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

My resulting json looks like this:

```
{"popularPurchases":[
     {"product":{"id":"123","face":"face1","size":"1","price":"500"},
       "recent":["smith","hambone","someone"]},
     {"product":{"id":"222","face":"face2","size":"2","price":"600"},
       "recent":["john","mary"]}
]}
```

My question is how can I get rid of the labels "popularPurchases" (including the ':') and "product (including the ':')?

My POJOs all look the same. Here is one of them:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PopularPurchase {

    @XmlElement
    private Product product;

    @XmlElement(name="recent")
    private List<String> users;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
    public List<String> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(List<String> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }   
}
```

I need it to look like this:

```
[
  {"id":"123","face":"face1","size":"1","price":"500"},
    "recent":["smith","hambone","someone"]},
  {"id":"222","face":"face2","size":"2","price":"600"},
       "recent":["john","mary"]}
]
```

I am producing the JSON with:

```
PopularPurchaseResponse ppResponse = new PopularPurchaseResponse();
ppResponse.setPopularPurchases(popularPurchases);       

builder = Response.status(200).entity(ppResponse);

return builder.build();
```

Comment: How are you producing the JSON?

Comment: PopularPurchaseResponse ppResponse = new PopularPurchaseResponse();
  ppResponse.setPopularPurchases(popularPurchases);  
    
  builder = Response.status(200).entity(ppResponse);
  
  return builder.build();

Sorry about the formatting. See above

Comment: I am assuming that is what you are returning from an endpoint? Is Jackson handling the conversion to JSON?

Comment: Yes. That code is at the end. Yes. I am using Jackson.

Comment: Have you tried configuring your mapper? `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);` See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837018/jackson-json-deserialization-ignore-root-element-from-json

Comment: I have not. Does this require a different way to return the result other than the above? This seems like it would affect all of the root value wrapping. I still need the 'recent' label.

Comment: You could try to add @XMLTransient annotation on those fields/get methods that you don't want to be serialized to JSON.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32097870/2587435

Comment: I want all of the fields I don't want the [label] : in front of some of it