# Ignore RootNode and custom mapping in Jackson/spring/Java

Tags: java, spring, jackson, deserialization

How i can ignore rootname if I dont need it? I need only bill.

if I remove "version" from json work fine..

my error on console log

```java
2019-07-27 19:20:14.874  WARN 12516 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected token (FIELD_NAME), expected END_OBJECT: Current token not END_OBJECT (to match wrapper object with root name 'bill'), but FIELD_NAME; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (FIELD_NAME), expected END_OBJECT: Current token not END_OBJECT (to match wrapper object with root name 'bill'), but FIELD_NAME
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 2]]
```

my json look like this

```
{
    "bill":
    {
        "siteId":"gkfhuj-00",
        "billId":"d6334954-d1c2-4b51-bb10-11953d9511ea"
        },
    "version":"1"
}
```

my class for json
i try use JsonIgnoreProperties but its dont help also i write "version"

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName(value = "bill")
public class Bill {

    private String siteId;
    private String billId;

//getters and setters
```

my post method lisen object Bill

```java
    @PostMapping("/bill")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> getBill(@RequestBody Bill bill)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson json deserialization, ignore root element from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837018/jackson-json-deserialization-ignore-root-element-from-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are relying on the `Spring boot` through annotations and `Jackson`, custom deserializer will work flawless in here. You have to create the deserializer class as show below

```
public class BillDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Bill> {

    public BillDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public BillDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Bill deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        JsonNode billNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        Bill bill = new Bill();
        bill.setSiteId(billNode.get("bill").get("siteId").textValue());
        bill.setBillId(billNode.get("bill").get("billId").textValue());      
        return bill;
    }
}
```

Now you have to instruct your `Jackson` to use this deserializer instead of the default one for the `Bill` class. This is done by registering the desearilizer. It can be done through a simple annotation on the `Bill` class like `@JsonDeserialize(using = BillDeserializer.class)`

Your `Bill` class will typically look as specified below

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = BillDeserializer.class)
public class Bill {

    private String siteId;
    private String billId;

//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: No ways to make annotations only ? with out 1 more class

Comment: Not without scarifying the spring default jackson mapping

Comment: This implementation gives the flexibility to have any level of custom nested mapping

Comment: But i can make 1 more class like
```java
public class Example {
private Bill bill;
private String version;
```

Comment: I didn't follow what you are asking. Is adding a class not an option for you?