# How could I deserialize a JSON property into Java Object in Jackson

Tags: jackson, rest-assured, jackson-databind

Given this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 38943,
    "title": "Appetere Platonem Tempor Interesset Natum",
    "description": "epicuri alia atqui",
    "visibility": "PUBLIC",
    "picture_url": null,
    "logo_picture": null,
    "owner_id": 51065,
    "created_at": "2021-08-16T05:59:15.325Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-08-16T05:59:15.325Z",
    "counts": {
      "subscriptions": 0,
      "spots": 0,
      "comments": 0,
      "impressions": 0,
      "respots": 0,
      "attachments": 0
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 51065,
      "name": "Jon",
      "screen_name": "jon",
      "url": null,
      "location": null,
      "profile_picture": null,
      "picture_url": null,
      "header_picture": null,
      "about": null,
      "counts": {
        "maps": 26
      }
    },
    "map_settings": {
      "editor_access": [
        "can_none.map",
        "can_create.spots",
        "can_create.events",
        "can_create.comments",
        "can_create.attachments",
        "can_create.collaborators"
      ],
      "visitor_access": [
        "can_none.map",
        "can_none.spots",
        "can_none.events",
        "can_create.comments",
        "can_create.attachments",
        "can_none.collaborators"
      ],
      "respotting_to_this_map": false
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

How could I deserialize the data property into a MapDTO like this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MapDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String visibility;
    @JsonAlias("picture_url")
    private String pictureUrl;
    @JsonAlias("logo_picture")
    private String logoPicture;
    @JsonAlias("owner_id")
    private Integer ownerId;
    @JsonAlias("created_at")
    private String createdAt;
    @JsonAlias("updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;
    private MapCountsDTO counts;
    @JsonAlias("map_settings")
    private MapSettingsDTO mapSettings;
    
}
```

I've tried with a custom deserializer, but it looks cumbersome to get all the properties by name and then create a new MapDTO object based on those and the nested objects. If the structure changes I have to change the deserializer and the DTO itself. It would be easier to let Jackson do the deserialization starting from a given root. I'm using Jackson  2.12.4 through RestAssured 4.4.0. I'd like to avoid creating unnecessary wrapper classes.

Comment: If you would have only one property on the top level you could use `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` feature. Take a look at: [Jackson json deserialization, ignore root element from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837018/jackson-json-deserialization-ignore-root-element-from-json). But in this case it will not work. The simplest and most reliable way is to create a root class with two properties one for the `data` and second one for the `meta` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [jsonshema2pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
This tool generates models for you.

All you need:

1. Copy and paste your JSON response to the window
2. Select on the radio group "Annotation style" radio button "Jackson 2.x"
3. Click on the "Preview" button
4. Profit.

Comment: I know that tool but that would generate a Data class for me which is basically a wrapper. On top of that in other responses the data property would represent another type of Object thus I would end up with DataMapDTO, UserDataDTO, etc. I would have to always extract to DataMapDTO first with RestAssured then get the MapDTO out of that.

Comment: I read your question not carefully.
Right now I'm using nested wrapper classes, but I'm also curious about how to make a flat structure, so I'll keep an eye on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this? https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // version 2.11.1  
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; // version 2.11.1
/* ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = om.readValue(myJsonString), Root.class); */
public class Counts{
    public int subscriptions;
    public int spots;
    public int comments;
    public int impressions;
    public int respots;
    public int attachments;
    public int maps;
}

public class User{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String screen_name;
    public Object url;
    public Object location;
    public Object profile_picture;
    public Object picture_url;
    public Object header_picture;
    public Object about;
    public Counts counts;
}

public class MapSettings{
    public List<String> editor_access;
    public List<String> visitor_access;
    public boolean respotting_to_this_map;
}

public class Data{
    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String description;
    public String visibility;
    public Object picture_url;
    public Object logo_picture;
    public int owner_id;
    public Date created_at;
    public Date updated_at;
    public Counts counts;
    public User user;
    public MapSettings map_settings;
}

public class Meta{
    public int code;
}

public class Root{
    public Data data;
    public Meta meta;
}
```